# Cumcount with reset in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a following problem. I need to compute a cumcount but I would like to reset the counter always when the series is interupted.
See example:

```py
data = { 'col_1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 'col_2': [3, 2, 1, 0, -3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I tried this but it gives me a wrong output:

```py
df["seq"] = df.groupby(["col_1"]).cumcount()
```

What I want is:

```py
data = { 'col_1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 'col_2': [3, 2, 1, 0, -3], 'seq': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]}
```

How can I do it, please?

Comment: What do you mean by the series is interrupted?

Comment: @DaniMesejo interrupted means that I have `a` in the first and second row but then in the last row. I would like to check this when doing `cumcount()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df["seq"] = df.groupby((df["col_1"] != df["col_1"].shift()).cumsum())["col_1"].cumcount()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  col_1  col_2  seq
0     a      3    0
1     a      2    1
2     b      1    0
3     b      0    1
4     a     -3    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that as you are interested in *runs* (like in run-length encoding) [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) might be better suited for this task, consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','a']})
df['seq'] = [i for k, g in itertools.groupby(col1) for i in range(len(list(g)))]
print(df)
```

output

```
  col1  seq
0    a    0
1    a    1
2    b    0
3    b    1
4    a    0
```

Comment: Elegant way, thanks!