# "Cumcount with Reset" and "Keep Last with Reset" in Python

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a follow up question related to this [prior StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616956/cumcount-with-reset-in-python).

Suppose I have the following NumPy array:

```py
import numpy as np
v = np.array([
  0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3,
  3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0,
  0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2,
  2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

I am trying to obtain a list of all the repeating-element sequences and their starting indices. My hunch is that using Pandas is the most straightforward way to achieve this.

Using the previously referenced StackOverflow answer, I write the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['digit'])
df["seq_len"] = df.groupby(
    (df["digit"] != df["digit"].shift()).cumsum()
    )["digit"].cumcount()+1
```

Producing the result:

```
    digit  seq_len
0       0        1
1       0        2
2       0        3
3       1        1
4       3        1
..    ...      ...
89      0        1
90      0        2
91      0        3
92      0        4
93      1        1
```

The last thing I need is to remove the duplicates along the "digit" column in such a way that the last "seq_len" value is kept. Normally, you could use Pandas `duplicated` or `drop_duplicates`, however these functions don't do any resetting along the column.

What I **don't** want is:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset='digit', keep='last')
    digit  seq_len
22      3        3
88      2        3
92      0        4
93      1        1
```

What I **do** want is something like:

```
>>> magic_function(df)
    digit  seq_len
2       0        3
3       1        1
5       3        2
10      1        5
..    ...      ...
88      2        3
92      0        4
93      1        1
```

Of course, if I do "index - seq_len + 1", I can obtain the true starting indices, e.g.,

```
index    digit  seq_len
0            0        3
3            1        1
4            3        2
6            1        5
..         ...      ...
86           2        3
89           0        4
92           1        1
```

So anyways, looking for any advice on an efficient `magic_function()` to do the above. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) with [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
m = df["digit"].ne(df["digit"].shift())
grp = df.groupby(m.cumsum(), group_keys=False)

df["seq_len"] = grp["digit"].cumcount().add(1)

out = grp.apply(lambda g: g.loc[~g["digit"].duplicated(keep="last")])
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    digit  seq_len
2       0        3
3       1        1
5       3        2
10      1        5
11      0        1
..    ...      ...
83      0        7
85      1        2
88      2        3
92      0        4
93      1        1

[43 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but this seems to work:

```py
v = np.array([
  0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3,
  3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0,
  0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2,
  2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['digit'])
df["seq_len"] = df.groupby((df["digit"] != df["digit"].shift()).cumsum())["digit"].cumcount()+1

# The new stuff:
s = df["digit"].diff()[1:] != 0
df.loc[list(s[s].index - 1) + [len(df) - 1]]
```

Comment: Nice work! @Timeless's answer is a bit more readable but this works just as well. 

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [builtin groupby functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html#seriesgroupby-computations-descriptive-stats) `first`/`last` and `size`. For the last index, I'm using a simple lambda, but I have a feeling there's an even more straightforward way I'm forgetting.

```
s = df['digit']
s.groupby(
    s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum().rename('group'),
    ).agg(
        last_index=lambda x: x.index[-1],
        digit='first',
        seq_len='size',
    )
```

```
       last_index  digit  seq_len
group                            
1               2      0        3
2               3      1        1
3               5      3        2
...           ...    ...      ...
41             88      2        3
42             92      0        4
43             93      1        1

[43 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This one is also a very readable answer! Thank you so much, @wjandrea!

Answer (score 2):

This should work as well:

```
(df.assign(seq_len = df.groupby(df['digit'].diff().ne(0).cumsum())['digit'].transform('size'))
.loc[df['digit'].iloc[::-1].diff().ne(0)])
```

or

```
m = df['digit'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df.assign(seq_len = df.groupby(m)['digit'].cumcount()+1).groupby(m).tail(1)
```

or

```
m = df['digit'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df.assign(seq_len = df.groupby(m)['digit'].cumcount()+1).loc[lambda x: x.groupby(m)['seq_len'].idxmax()]
```

or

```
(df.groupby(
    [0,df[0].diff().ne(0).cumsum()],sort=False).size()
    .droplevel(1)
    .rename_axis('digit')
    .reset_index(name = 'seq_len'))
```

Output:

```
    digit  seq_len
2       0        3
3       1        1
5       3        2
10      1        5
11      0        1
12      2        1
13      3        1
14      2        1
16      1        2
18      0        2
19      1        1
22      3        3
23      2        1
27      0        4
30      1        3
31      2        1
32      1        1
37      0        5
38      1        1
40      2        2
41      1        1
43      0        2
46      1        3
49      0        3
...
85      1        2
88      2        3
92      0        4
93      1        1
```